# Can static electricity from polyester cloth destroy a laptop?

Tags: laptop

So a few days ago I left my laptop for a whole day on a 100% polyester cloth. It was closed, turned off, and not charging. I set a workbook with metal parts on the top of the laptop. When I tried to turn the laptop on, it wouldn't turn on. Only the Lenovo logo showed up. I wasn't able to boot it or do anything with it, however I was able to get to BIOS. It is a new Lenovo that came out this year. I just want to know if it was my fault or what could have happened to it, and if the service place will be able to repair it.

Comment: electro-magnetic fields can change the little interruptors (transistors) that make a memory, if your bios boots then put your system on a booteable pendrive and reinstall it from the bios

Comment: I tried that, I also tried to remove my battery from BIOS also that didn't help at all.

Comment: Does it hang at the Logo or try to go past it to a blank screen with a blinking cursor or just a blank screen? Do you see your HDD/SSD in the BIOS?

Comment: no blinking screen it actually is in service right now so I don't remember about that HDD/SSD

Comment: The circumstances make me think of other potential problem causes : too much weight pushing a hard drive cable out of its socket.  Since you are able to get to BIOS, you know that 90% of the hardware components are working.  It might be as simple as unplugging and replugging the hard drive cables / connectors.  Look in the BIOS to see if it detects the hard drive.

Comment: Setting a laptop on a cloth of any kind can't generate static electricity, and setting something with metal parts on top can't damage it from static electricity.  Whatever the problem is, it's just coincidence, although setting something heavy on top could flex the case and potentially damage something.  There's no way for people here to know what might be wrong or what it would take to repair it.

Comment: Well, the workbook weighted like 100 grams I don't know if it was too heavy.

Comment: why u trying with the battery? this most definitely has to do with the hard drive getting deconfigurated. try changing the hard drive

Comment: I already took it to authorised service just wanted to know if I possibly caused this somehow.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, yes. Static electricity can destroy a laptop or its components easily. Every time a crucial component such as the CPU, or motherboard is handled, they instruct to make sure you ground yourself before you pick it up to discharge any static. In fact, to quote Mr. Programs in the comment above, an electro-magnetic field can also destroy memory.

To answer a question on whether or not someone can fix this. Possibly...

My method of figuring out if my data is still there is to boot from a Live USB of linux and try to mount the hard drive.

Another thing you can do is go into your BIOS and hit one of the F- buttons to start system diagnostics. Go through the prompts and test your hardware. Every BIOS should be equipped with the ability to diagnose its own hardware such as the HD and RAM. This would tell you if any of your hardware was permanently damaged. If the BIOS booted, then the CPU should be in good shape. Otherwise, the computer wouldn't boot. Good luck and I hope you find your solution.

Comment: Yes a laptop can be damaged by static electricity, but not in the way described in the question.  Sorry, but this whole answer stems from a faulty premise.

Comment: Ok, you are correct about not damaging it in the way I think (metal chassis in the laptop will protect from static shock.) I am right about static electricity being damaging to a computer. If the internals of the computer are exposed (RAM, CPU, Hard Drive, etc.) then a static discharge will damage the exposed circuitry. However, I am not sure about static electricity at the bottom, then metal parts at the top. I'm not sure if it will in fact create an electric field that can be damaging to a Hard Drive. Like passing a strong magnet over it.

Comment: You get a static discharge due to a difference in potential. Something needs to create a charge. The laptop will be at the same potential unless it is plugged in or some electrical component is in contact with something grounded. If you build up a static charge walking across a rug, pick up your plugged-in laptop, and touch something like an exposed port, that could discharge through some internal circuitry and damage something. But laptop components are generally protected inside the case. It would be hard for a static discharge to pass through the case and damage something inside.  (cont'd)

Comment: It's a different matter if the case is apart and you are handling internal components.  For that, it's important to take static precautions.

Comment: Ok fixer 1234, thank you for clarifying. I guess I over exaggerated the danger of static electricity vs. laptops.

Comment: No internal components have never been exposed in this case. It was a new laptop everything worked just fine before that.

Comment: Nevertheless user972532, the shop the computer was taken to will probably try to access the hard drive to see if the data is still there.